# Typing a generic function that accepts an object and its property name, expecting obj[propName] to be of certain type, e. g. sumBy, mapBy

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's my sorry attempt to type a `mapBy`:

```
export function mapBy<T, K = keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): T[K][] {
  return array.map((item: T) => item[key]);
}
```

TypeScript complains: `Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'. ts(2536)`

My second case is more tricky:

```
export default function sumBy<T, K = keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): number {
  return array.reduce((result: number, item: T) => {
    return result + item[key];
  }, 0);
}
```

Here I somehow need to tell TypeScript that `T` must be an object that has a `number` in `T[K]`.

Please help me type this functions properly in strict mode.

**I expect a call to `sumBy()` to be marked as a type error when the first argument does not have a `number` at the property with given name.**

UPD: [TS Playground code sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgArQM4HsTIN4CwAUMqciHALYQBcyGYUoA5gNzFnIDuEwzAFmDogArpQBG0dkQC+xYhAAeAByxQwyACYR4IgDYaYIkAjDAc9MQCEAngB4AKsiWQQmjPmQBtUNsU0GJhBmAF1hMUkoZBkAGmQAaWdFV3dkAGsIGywYZAcAPgAKOCgoOBs6By8QuIzyhIBKcIloTw5kKAgwEShcYtKbADoOzREkAoKOjH0hcgjoOOBISgr65ABePNaSMg6unvaIKYNkAGpkRYhKL1qQ1mQ22OQABnq74jkiYgQcBmRlCCwyj0tDQmBwVXW3japDw5CoIIA5AA1LAANzgCLiPD4gjoAHYntEYtDPBRqHQEegwDYMVjeAIZgAOQmxYi3eSfTkcgD03Ny-GAHgw-Cw+k0yHgwD03EW-HoWGoYAFwWQemAGWQACIlP9TBBxcVmABGZBgLDIfhwVEoZRQQHQanIQ1GgZklDZU02f6zZpQTVfH4aSbTSFTSi2Ar-QHAuIIt0I14c74gbDAgZ6LDMCaHaavIA)

Comment: Presumably `mapBy()` should return `T[K][]` and not `T[K]`

Comment: @jcalz Thank you, kind sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you are facing is that `K = keyof T` just gives `K` a [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) specification of `keyof T` if the compiler fails to infer `K` or if someone manually specifies `T` but not `K`.  Nothing stops the compiler from inferring or a caller from manually specifying some completely different type like `Date | string | Array<RegExp>`, and thus the compiler really cannot safely index into `T` with `K`.

What you want is to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `K` to be assignable to `keyof T` using the syntax `K extends keyof T`.  (so, `extends` and not `=`). This fixes `mapBy()`:

```
export function mapBy<T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): T[K][] {
    return array.map((item: T) => item[key]);
}
```

For `sumBy()` you also need a second constraint: you want `K extends keyof T`, but you also want `T extends Record<K, number>` where [`Record<K, V>` is a utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) which means a type with a property at key (or a union of keys) `K` whose value is of type `V`.   So `T extends Record<K, number>` means that `T` must have a property at key `K` whose value is type `number`.  That's enough for the compiler to accept that `result + item[key]` is a valid operation:

```
export default function sumBy<T extends Record<K, number>, K extends keyof T>(
  array: T[], 
  key: K
): number {
    return array.reduce((result: number, item: T) => {
        return result + item[key];
    }, 0);
}
```

This has the desired effect of only allowing `sumBy()` calls where the `key` parameter corresponds to a `number`-valued property for every element in the `array` parameter type:

```
const arr = [{ a: 1, b: 2 }, { a: 3, b: "hello" }, { a: 6, c: true }];

console.log(sumBy(arr, "a")) // 10
sumBy(arr, "b") // error! Types of property 'b' are incompatible. string is not number
sumBy(arr, "c") // error! Types of property 'c' are incompatible. undefined is not number
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Comment: OMG, thank you so much! I did not know it's allowed to do circular references in generic types. Great solution and great explanation! This is so cool: `Type 'Person' is not assignable to type 'Record<"name", number>'. Types of property 'name' are incompatible.`

Comment: The compiler allows *some* recursion in types, but balks on others.  If you tried `T extends U, U extends T` you'd get a circularity error.  I have an intuition for which such things are allowed and which are not, but I don't know if I could spell it out to others, unfortunately.